# Div same surrounding margin

Tags: html, css

I want the div's inside the container to be at equal distance.

Check the fiddle I have created in it there is a main container with two divs inside it. How can I have it like the margin between the image div's and margin on right and left of the div's be same?

http://jsfiddle.net/5b73gew0/

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-ptcuEsGVB4I/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAABQM/WKCwt2vYBko/s46-c-k-no/photo.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-ptcuEsGVB4I/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAABQM/WKCwt2vYBko/s46-c-k-no/photo.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>

#main{
    width: 100%;
}
.image{
    float: left;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Update:
As you all have commented out that its unclear what Im trying to achieve, so here is a bit more explanation:

```
[margin] image-div-1 [margin] image-div-2 [margin]
```

I want margin to be same, so the 2 div's will be centered aligned in the main div, but will also have an equal margin in between them too.

*Margin: You can also say it as Spacing*

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for.

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: I think he's trying to `justify' the divs.

Comment: I have edited my question, please check ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you need to go is get all the imgs widths together `imgWidth` then find the window width `windowWidth` then determine the margin `dMargin` which is `windowWidth` - `imgWidth` divided by the number of imgs + 1

(for 2 elements there is 3 white spaces 1 to the left of the first img 1 inbetween them and 1 to the right) as so: `[margin] image1 [margin] image2 [margin]`

Then you need to apply that full margin to only the left of the first img and the right of the second image and then only half of `dMargin` to the rest (because the right of img1 and left of img2 need to be half of the `dMargin` so that together it is the full `dMargin`).

Which will effectively evenly distribute all elements as shown here:

Code Snippet:

```js
function determineMargin() {
    var imgs = $(".image > img");
    var imgWidth = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        imgWidth += imgs[i].width;
    }

    //Now that we know the spacing the images take up, lets find out the window width

    var windowWidth = $(window).width();

    var dMargin = (windowWidth - imgWidth) / (imgs.length + 1);

    for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        var tempDMargin = dMargin + imgs[i].width / 2;
        if (i == 0) {
            imgs[i].style.marginLeft = dMargin + "px";
            imgs[i].style.marginRight = dMargin / 2 + "px";
        } else if (i == imgs.length) {
            imgs[i].style.marginLeft = dMargin / 2 + "px";
            imgs[i].style.marginRight = dMargin + "px";
        } else {
            imgs[i].style.marginLeft = dMargin / 2 + "px";
            imgs[i].style.marginRight = dMargin / 2 + "px";
        }
    }
}

determineMargin();

$(window).resize(function () {
    determineMargin();
});
```

```css
#main {
    width: 100%;
}
.image {
    float:left;
}
body {
    margin:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-ptcuEsGVB4I/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAABQM/WKCwt2vYBko/s46-c-k-no/photo.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-ptcuEsGVB4I/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAABQM/WKCwt2vYBko/s46-c-k-no/photo.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

or Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xzrn7n6p/1/

Comment: I'm guessing he wants neither. But means to distribute the images evently over the 100% width container. Spacing them out evenly.

Comment: This is close to what I want, but see margin on the left of first div should be equal to margin between the 2 div's and margin on the right of 2nd div ..

Comment: @Haider OK fixed, added event on `$(window).resize()` so that if they resize the window it recalculates the margins!

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/5b73gew0/

No matter how many divs, there will always be a constant margin between them, to the right and to the left.

```
#main{
    width: 100%;
}
.image{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.last {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

and the last div needs to get:

```
<div class="image last">
    <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-ptcuEsGVB4I/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAABQM/WKCwt2vYBko/s46-c-k-no/photo.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: But I think he always wants the images centered on the screen not pulled left.  But who really knows. lol

Answer (score 0):

I made a fiddle to get what you want : http://jsfiddle.net/h9g44Ldx/

```
#main{
width: 100%;
}
.image{
float: left;
margin: auto 5%;
width:40%;
}
.first
{
 margin-right:0;
}
img{
 margin: auto 0;
 width:46px;
}
```

Comment: This answer isn't doing what he wants.  This is expanding the imgs and distorting them...

Comment: Well, you can easely remove the img width:100%;

Comment: You can, but that makes your answer wrong, as it does not even distribute the elements...